# Delphi XE8 strange Header

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

On Delphi XE8 normally headers with a small website show up on the welcome page.
Currently I get strange text there, for example:
****#0  JError::throwError(JException Object ([] => 1,[] => 500,[] => Application Instantiation Error,[] => ,[] => /var/www/html/etcms/libraries/joomla/error/error.php,[] => 175,[] => ,[] => ,[] => ,[] => ,[] => Array ([0] => Array ([file] => /var/www/html/etcms/libraries/joomla/error/error.php,[line] => 175,[function] => __con****

This is just a small excerpt, the text is much longer.
Does anyone know what causes Delphi to display this ?

Comment: Welcome page in Delphi is basically just a webpage with some Java Scripts on it to allow it to get some information from Delphi ide like Recent Projects list. Based on the strange text I guess it may be failing to get proper handle to read information from.

Comment: I would not care about the welcome page if there were no recent projects list. In earlier dephi versions the recent projects were displayed with and without internet access. When I am on the road without internet access I have to load recent projects via the menu. This works too but is less handy.

Comment: As far as I know "Recent projects" part of the welcome page should load even when you are offline. That is because the webpage that is used is stored locally but it does loads some of the content from the EMB server.

Answer (score 0):

The welcome page works now again without any obvious reason. Castalia is already disable so the problem must be on embarcaderos side. I think no one else than they can explain and solve the problem.
So this case can be closed.